# Cannot create Firefox context menu

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I've been trying to create a Firefox addon, to download pics/vids/galleries from Instagram. The idea is to right click -> context menu -> download media. So far I haven't been able to create a (context) menu.

borderify.js (main script)

```
function mcreated(){
console.log("maybe it worked");
}

console.log("HELLOHELLO");

browser.menus.create({
    id: "contextDownloadMenu",
    title: "DOWNLOADHERE",
    contexts: ["all"]
}, mcreated());

console.log(browser.runtime.lastError);
```

manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "please no",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.instagram.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": ["menus"]

}
```

The output I'm getting in the console is "HELLOHELLO", nothing else. No error, or anything else.

I've done everything as shown in mozillas guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus

Comment: First off, you should just pass `mcreated` as the second parameter, instead of `mcreated()`. You want to pass the function, not what the function returns to `browser.menus.create`

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting no output at all, not even "HELLOHELLO"